# Discover SQL Server installation on the network - How to detect all of them?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I come with a small issue. I would like to discover every "wild" SQL Server installation in my company but I don't know how to make that happen.

I search the web and find this PowerShell command to execute to find all SQL Server installation on the local network:

`[System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator]::Instance.GetDataSources()`

When I execute this on a cluster node, it returns the SQL Server instances installed on this cluster but not the ones installed on another cluster in the same network (both clusters are in 10.4.4.0/24). Also, the results does not return the SSAS installation.

Another small issue is that the "version" result is not correct. It returns the 11.0.2100.60 value instead of 11.0.3393

My questions are:

1. Is there another way to detect every SQL Server installation on the network? AD query?
2. How can I be sure that the information returned are correct?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I started off using AD, but the information there can easily get out of date, and worse, not all servers will properly register as having a SQL Server instance on them. Using Server Management Objects (SMO) is even worse, in addition to being very slow.

I ended up with using an `nmap` script to scan all servers on the internal network for port 1433, as follows:

```
nmap -oX - -T5 -p 1433 -sC [ip range]
```

This outputs an XML file (`-oX`) to the standard output (`-`) with a timeout of 5 seconds (`-T5`) scanning port 1433 (`-p 1433`) running the default script for that port (`-sC`), which opens a connection to the server and detects the version of SQL Server used. `nmap` has other output options too, but the XML is convenient to manipulate in a PowerShell script (this uses v3):

```cs
$nmap = "nmap"
$range = "192.168.[whatever]"
$servers = [xml] (&$nmap -oX - -T5 -p 1433 -sC $range)
$sqlinstancesraw = $servers.nmaprun.selectnodes("//service[@name='ms-sql-s'][@conf=10]")
$sqlinstances = $sqlinstancesraw |% { 
    $server = $_.parentnode.parentnode.parentnode
    $address = $server.address.addr
    $hostname = $server.hostnames.hostname.name
    $product = $_.product
    $version = $_.version
    new-object -type psobject | add-member -passthru -notepropertymembers @{
        address = $address
        hostname = $hostname
        product = $product
        version = $version
    }
}
$sqlinstances | Export-Csv "servers.csv"
```

Obviously, this will fail for servers that are firewalled internally or that run instances on other ports than 1433, but those are not common scenarios.

Detecting SSAS should be possible similarly, but I haven't looked into that -- in particular, `nmap` has no standard script for SSAS the way it does for SQL Server. You might get away with using SMO to test for SSAS once you've narrowed down the list of likely server candidates.

Be aware that `nmap` can be seen as suspect by administrators because it can be used to map vulnerabilities on networks you have no access to. When you're using it on your own network, of course, there's no problem, but if you're not the network administrator you may want to tell them what you're doing regardless. They may even get enthusiastic. :-)

Comment: Thanks for this :)
I'll try as soons as I have the "approval" from the network guys!