# Trying to get a list of databases in each server, but it is timing out. Any idea how to get around this?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm just experimenting with getting a list of databases from each server I have access to in work.  I don't actually need to know the answer, just playing around.  Anyways, my code is as follows:

```
var alldatabases = new List<string>();
var directories = new DirectoryEntry();

var serversList = (from DirectoryEntry child in directories.Children 
    where child.Name == "WindowsADGroupName" 
    select child into serverChild from DirectoryEntry secondchild in serverChild.Children 
    select secondchild.Name).ToList();

serversList.RemoveAll(x => !x.Contains("CN="));

foreach (string server in serversList)
    {
        try
            {
                var s = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(server);
                alldatabases.AddRange(from Database db in s.Databases 
                where db.Name != "master" 
                && db.Name != "model" 
                && db.Name != "msdb" 
                && db.Name != "tempdb" 
                select db.Name);
            }
        catch (Exception)
            {
                 continue;
            }
    }
```

It keeps timing out at the line

```
var s = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server(server);
```

> "Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out. You must continue execution to reenable function evaluation."

It doesn't crash, it seems like it just keeps trying to access the server?  The output window displays the following message repeatedly:

> "A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionFailureException' occurred in Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll"

I honestly have no idea what I'm doing, I've just got nothing to do in work, and thought I'd try and mess about with this to see if I could get a list of all the databases in all of the servers I have access to.  And this is as far as I've managed to get.

Anyone got any ideas or explanation as to what's happening here?

Comment: "Function evaluation disabled because..." is a debugger notification, not something you'd see at runtime. It seems probable some servers are just plain unreachable or turned off. Is `serversList` a list of all SQL Servers, or just a list of *all servers*, most of which won't be running SQL Server?

Comment: Do you have permission on the servers where SQL Server is hosted?

Comment: serversList is a list of all servers.  Some may not be running SQL Server.  Some I may not have access to.  I'm just getting a list of all servers within that group.  Then trying to iterate through them.  Is there no way to skip the ones that don't have an instance of SQL Server or that I don't have access to?  Assuming I don't know in advance which ones I have access to, and which ones have a SQL Server instance.

Comment: Incidentally, I have had cause to list all databases on all servers everywhere. For this, `Parallel.ForEach` over a manually issued `SELECT name FROM sys.databases` is orders of magnitude faster than SMO. For the list of reachable servers, if there is no ready list available, [`nmap` can get that quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26356910/4137916). Without `nmap`, using a small `Connect Timeout` parameter to `SqlConnection` will do as well (unless your DNS is slow). How you do this quickly with SMO, I don't know; I've basically given up on it and the system views are my friends.

Comment: Interesting stuff Jeroen, thanks for the input.

Comment: Sorry, for `Parallel.ForEach`, read `serverList.AsParallel().Select(s => getDatabases(s))`. Make `getDatabases` catch exceptions so you get back results even if servers are unreachable. For trivial parallelism like this, PLINQ is wonderful.

Comment: Try try catch to skip over unreachable servers.

Comment: No idea how to do that :)